# C# programming for Barcode scanner: RS232 vs Keyboard Wedge vs USB

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I am about to purchase the Metrologic Quantim T barcode scanner which comes with either RS232, Keyboard Wedge or USB. I will need to create a program to read from this scanner and am trying to make a decision which to go for. So I guess the main questions would be:
* What is the quickest interface to write for?
* Which is the quickest interface to get the information from? (i.e. would I need to poll, or can the info be pushed to me and I can just handle an event?)
* Which would provide the most flexibility?
* Which is most future proof?

Help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are going to do, you might not need a special API to code against.  Most(read all) barcode scanners will scan in a barcode and translate it to keyboard presses.  In which case, you can use simple text boxes to accept the barcode input.  This, of course, might not be the case if the application will not be a standard windows form application.

Just something to consider,
Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Hi i write lib for metrologic scaner with RS232 but when we finished our project my PM told me that they buy some lib or api for metrologic scaners so you better try find those api or some other, good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with RS232 in the past, you read the data from a serial port.  I've never done any serial port programming under Windows so I can't say how easy or hard it is.

Keyboard wedges look just like the keyboard and thus are very easy to work with *IF* you can ensure the input goes to the correct field no matter what.  If you can control the input focus well enough it's easy, otherwise it's quite a pain.

I've never used USB to know what it's like.

Industrial equipment APIs often stink, I would be leery of the USB route until I saw what it was like.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Metrologic's barcode scanner in one of the projects of the company I worked for.

We found keyboard wedge as the most elegant and flexible solution. The scanner will send you specific key (I can't remember which one, I think you can also set it to your own pleasure) before and after sending the exact barcode number. So, just wait for the specific key from the keyboard and read barcode number until you hit ending key.

Once again, we found this most elegant solution for our needs and this approach was rather easy to implement.